# Join 2 tables with multiple references in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have 2 tables, Table1 and Table2.

```
**Table1**
Id      Name
------------
14443   Michael
55658   Brian
84321   Lisa
335896  NULL
1035    Maya
5221296 Brenda


**Table2**
Id1     Id2         MatchLevel
--------------------------
14443   5221296     0,5192
14443   84321       0,8647
14443   182347      0,6897
**1035  14443**     0,9999
14443   4572311     0,8569
63547   14443       0,9563
335896  14443       0,9418
14443   5221296     0,6942

**55658 5221296**   0,9928
55658   84321       0,8647
55658   182347      0,6897
1035    55658       0,6796
55658   4572311     0,8569
63547   55658       0,9563
335896  55658       0,9418
55658   5221296     0,6942
```

Id1 and Id2 in Table2 are references to Id in Table1

For each person(Id in Table1) I want to select the row in Table2 with the highest MatchLevel excluding the persons with NULL as Name.

### The above Tables should return something similar to this:

```
1035    14443       0,9999 (Michael)
55658   5221296     0,9928 (Brian)
```

How would the LINQ query look like? I'd appreciate if it's not a Lambda expression.

Comment: Do you have relations defined in your ORM mapping for this tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in the lines of:

```
var query1 = 
    (from t1 in table1s
    join t2 in table2s on t1.Id equals t2.Id1
    where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t1.Name)
    select new {t1.Name, t2.Id1, t2.Id2, t2.MatchLevel});

var query2 =
    (from t1 in table1s
    join t2 in table2s on t1.Id equals t2.Id2
    where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t1.Name)
    select new {t1.Name, t2.Id1, t2.Id2, t2.MatchLevel});


var query = query1.Union(query2).GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        Name = x.Key, 
        MatchLevel = x.Max(y => y.MatchLevel)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is written on the fly since you provide no data classes, so pardon any mistakes. I've also considered that empty names are taken out as well, so if that's not correct change the check in the query:

```
var result = (from con in Table2
join name1 in Table1 on con.Id1 equals name1.Id
join name2 in Table1 on con.Id2 equals name2.Id
where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name1.Name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name2.Name)
group new {con.Id1, con.Id2, con.MatchLevel, name1.Name, name2.Name} by name2 into grp
select new {res = grp.OrderbyDescending(x=>x.MatchLevel).FirstOrDefault()})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess you should have Table1 on the second join as well, right? Anyway this is not returning a list of all entries but just one. I need to have a complete list with the highest level for each name(Table1.Cid).